# Sorting map<String,String> by date(value) using stream Java

Tags: java, sorting, date, time, java-stream

I have Map with abbreviation as a key and time(duration) as a value

```
VBM=01:12.434
SVF=01:04.415
CSR=01:12.950
DRR=01:12.013
KMH=01:13.393
SPF=01:12.848
SVM=01:12.463
CLS=01:12.829
BHS=01:13.179
LHM=01:12.460
LSW=01:13.323
```

and I need to sort it from the shortest duration to the longest.

I use 4 big methods to do it and I wonder if I can do it easily with streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort a map, try the following. Be very sure to use a `LinkedHashMap` because it doesn't remain sorted otherwise. You can replace `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` with a `Comparator` of your choice.

```
map
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    Map.Entry::getValue,
    (e1, e2) -> e1,
    LinkedHashMap::new
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> unSortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    unSortedMap.put("VBM","01:12.434");
    unSortedMap.put("SVF","01:04.415");
    unSortedMap.put("CSR","01:12.950");
    unSortedMap.put("DRR","01:12.013");
    unSortedMap.put("KMH","01:13.393");
    unSortedMap.put("SPF","01:12.848");
    unSortedMap.put("SVM","01:12.463");
    unSortedMap.put("CLS","01:12.829");
    unSortedMap.put("BHS","01:13.179");
    unSortedMap.put("LHM","01:12.460");
    unSortedMap.put("LSW","01:13.323");
    System.out.println("Unsorted Map : " + unSortedMap);
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
    unSortedMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
            .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
        System.out.println("\n\n\nSorted Map   : " + unSortedMap);
```